# It possible set two pin with GPIO_Set cmsis function in stm32f10?

Tags: stm32, cmsis

It possible to set 2 pins high with `GPIO_SetBits(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)` like this:

```
GPIO_SetBis(GPIOA,PA1|PA2)
```

The online stm32f10 peripheral library ([here](http://stm32.kosyak.info/doc/group___g_p_i_o___exported___functions.html#ga9e1352eed7c6620e18af2d86f6b6ff8e)) said:

> This parameter can be any ***combination*** of GPIO_Pin_x where x can be (0..15)

But inside the `GPIO_SetBits` function there is:

```
assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));
```

It refers to a simple macro that exams each input as sigle pin:

```
(((PIN) == GPIO_Pin_0) || \ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Of cource it is possible. But you must write a new function,which has three paremeter.You can write easily when you analaysis GPIO_SetBits functions. It will be just similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about STM32 standard library provided by STM, then its not possible, see what standard library says ..

```
void GPIO_SetBits(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));
  assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));

  GPIOx->BSRRL = GPIO_Pin;
}
```

So it takes GPIOx and GPIO Pin as parameters and assign `GPIO_Pin` to `GPIOx-->BSRRL` register...

*However you can always make your own function to do the task for you .*